# Show that $f'''$ is strictly growing

Tags: calculus

How can i show that $f'''$ is strictly growing on $(0, 1/2)$. Would appreciate if someone could walk me through this one

$$ 
f(x) = \frac12\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right),\ x\in(-1,1).
$$

Comment: Welcome to Math Exchange. What have you tried? What do you think will work? Have you learned about applications of differentiation yet? We can't help you if we don't know what you know.

Comment: If $f'(x)>0$ then $f$ is increasing at $x$. Apply this $g = f'''$.

Comment: Hint: $$ 
\frac12\log\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right) = \frac12\log(1+x)-\frac12\log(1-x).
$$

Comment: @Math1000 so if i derivative this 3 times. (1/2) ln(1+x)− (1/2) ln(1−x), and its bigger than 0, then i know its growing. But how can i know if its strictly growing. Or is it the same as growing.

Comment: By strict or unstrict inequalities, i.e. $>$ vs $\geqslant$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*Hint.* Just differentiate away! Do it four times and note whether the fourth derivative is positive almost everywhere in the domain $(0,1/2).$ If it is, then you're done!

Comment: $4$ times? Not $3$?

Comment: Blindly differentiating is not recommended. Greg Martin's comment above should be used.

Comment: @KaboMurphy I didn't ask him to *blindly* differentiate, whatever that means in any case.

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari Yes four, since you're interested in the monotonicity of a third derivative. This is because the first derivative of a third derivative is a fourth derivative, obviously, whose sign tells the story of the monotonicity of the primitive.